# Select where value in row is different and update

Tags: postgresql

I have a large table that includes rows like the following:

**Query:**

```
select * 
from cartographic_text_vm 
where fid = 'osgb5000005104723440' 
order by ckpt;
```

**Results:**

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------+---------------------------------------------------------
change_history              | 2012-09-05,New
descriptive_group           | Buildings Or Structure
descriptive_term            |
feature_code                | 10026
fid                         | osgb5000005104723440
cartographic_text_version   | 1
make                        | Manmade
physical_level              | 50
physical_presence           |
text_render_anchor_position | 4
text_render_font            | 1
text_render_height          | 2.125
text_render_orientation     | 0
text_string                 | (Secondary)
theme                       | Buildings
version_date                | 2012-09-06 00:00:00
primary_key                 | 8240079
partition_key               | 2
random_number               | 9
geom                        | 0101000020346C000085EB51B8486B1B417B14AE47E9AFFB40
ckpt                        | 1
end_ckpts                   | {7}
transact_status             |

-[ RECORD 2 ]---------------+---------------------------------------------------------
change_history              | 2012-09-05,New,2015-10-25,TextChange
descriptive_group           | Buildings Or Structure
descriptive_term            |
feature_code                | 10026
fid                         | osgb5000005104723440
cartographic_text_version   | 2
make                        | Manmade
physical_level              | 50
physical_presence           |
text_render_anchor_position | 4
text_render_font            | 1
text_render_height          | 2.125
text_render_orientation     | 0
text_string                 | (secondary)
theme                       | Buildings
version_date                | 2015-10-26 00:00:00
primary_key                 | 8240079
partition_key               | 2
random_number               | 124
geom                        | 0101000020346C000085EB51B8486B1B417B14AE47E9AFFB40
ckpt                        | 7
end_ckpts                   | {61}
transact_status             |

-[ RECORD 3 ]---------------+---------------------------------------------------------
change_history              | 2012-09-05,New,2015-10-25,TextChange,2016-04-04,Modified
descriptive_group           | Buildings Or Structure
descriptive_term            |
feature_code                | 10026
fid                         | osgb5000005104723440
cartographic_text_version   | 3
make                        | Manmade
physical_level              | 50
physical_presence           |
text_render_anchor_position | 4
text_render_font            | 1
text_render_height          | 2.125
text_render_orientation     | 0
text_string                 | (secondary)
theme                       | Buildings
version_date                | 2016-04-05 00:00:00
primary_key                 | 123465 <- needs to be changed to 8240079
partition_key               | 2
random_number               | 135
geom                        | 0101000020346C0000AE47E17A446B1B41C3F5285CE7B0FB40
ckpt                        | 61
end_ckpts                   |
transact_status             |
```

I want to search for rows that have the same value for `fid`, but different values for `primary_key`. The database has a versioning extension enabled, so it's important that each version of a `fid` has the same `primary_key`.

When you look at the three records above, they are all in different checkpoints as denoted by the value in the `ckpt` field. The lowest number is the original version of the record, all of the records that have a higher `ckpt` value are modifications of that original record. I want to update any records that have a different `primary_key` from the original record to that value. As you can see in Record 3, the `primary_key` is `123456` which needs to be updated to the `primary_key` in record 1.

Any pointers in how the SQL should look?

Comment: For anyone searching for this in the future, the SQL query I ended up using was:

`update cartographic_text_vm set primary_key=new.primary_key from (select * from cartographic_text_vm where (fid, ckpt) in (select fid, min(ckpt) from cartographic_text_vm group by fid)) new where cartographic_text_vm.fid=new.fid and cartographic_text_vm.primary_key != new.primary_key;`

Comment: Please consider posting that as an answer (and accepting it later if no-one comes up with a better suggestion) instead of a comment. That's a common practice here, even when answering own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update cartographic_text_vm 
set primary_key = new.primary_key 
from 
    (select *  
     from cartographic_text_vm 
     where (fid, ckpt) in 
         (select fid, min(ckpt) 
          from cartographic_text_vm 
          group by fid)
    ) new 
where cartographic_text_vm.fid = new.fid 
  and cartographic_text_vm.primary_key != new.primary_key;
```